# How can you sign in to Palo Alto Global Protect when you have multiple Microsoft Profiles?

Tags: vpn

When I click "connect" in Global Protect 5.0.1, a message appears in the dialog:

```
Microsoft  

Sign in 

Sorry, but we’re having trouble with signing you in.

AADSTS50105: The signed in user 'xxx.xxx@otherdomain.com' is not assigned to a role for the application 'cc1a06de-b346-4e7e-b5fa-35b227c13063'(Palo Alto Networks - GlobalProtect).

Request Id:  xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (redacted)

Correlation Id:  xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (redacted)

Timestamp:  yyyy-mm-ddTxx:xx:xxZ (redacted)

Message:  AADSTS50105: The signed in user 'xxx.xxx@otherdomain.com' is not assigned to a role for the application 'cc1a06de-b346-4e7e-b5fa-35b227c13063'(Palo Alto Networks - GlobalProtect). 

Advanced diagnostics: Enable 

If you plan on getting support for an issue, turn this on and try to reproduce the error. This will collect additional information that will help to troubleshoot the issue.
```

Other information:

1. I have a Microsoft profile for "other domain".
2. I had uninstalled Internet Explorer 11 before installing Global Connect
3. Right clicking on the dialog indicates that the Internet Explorer 11 rendering engine is still being used for this dialog.  A "Back" menu item is available, but has no effect.  A "Properties" menu item is available and I can use the URL to log in to the NEW profile (e.g. in Chrome) but I am loath to re-install Internet Explorer 11 unless I really have to.